# Count the ratio of letter not matching

Tags: java, algorithm

> Given a reference string X and a mainstring Y, count the percentage that X doesnt occur in Y.
>   **MEANING:** eg `X = ABCD` and `Y = ABCDABRR` then we have the percentage 2/8 = 0.25 because the the 2RR's didn't align with `ABCD = X` and one more example, `X = ABCD, Y = ABCDABRD` then 1/8.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String mainS = "ABCDEABCDERRCRR";
String ref = "ABCDE";
double fails = 0; //count the fails.
double len = mainS.length(); //length of main String.
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    String charAti = mainS.substring(i, i+1);
    if(ref.contains(charAti)){
       //PASS
    } else{
     ++fails;
    }
}
double ratio = fails/len;
System.out.println("Failure ratio is: " + ratio);
```

}

This works, I believe `O(N)`, but can I get faster?

Comment: Why the answer is 2/8?

Comment: @square1001, main string had 8 characters and $RR$ didnt align so Im guessing thats why?

Comment: @Amad27 I think that string "ABCDABRR" contains "ABCD" only 1 times, so I think the answer is 1/5.

Comment: @square1001, I think he is counting all individual characters

Comment: @Amad27 OK, so X="ABC" and Y="ABCDEBCAD" the answer is 3/9?

Answer (score 1):

For the arguments you provide, in which ref is short, this is a perfectly reasonable approach. However, you are calling contains() multiple times. The Java documentation does not specify the implementation or the complexity of this functions, but it is required, in the general case, to see if one string contains another, so the cost of each call to contains() is likely to grow at least linearly with the length of the string searched. Your complexity is probably more accurately described as O(mn) where m and n are the lengths of the two strings involved.

You would have a lower theoretical complexity if you used the ref string to populate a HashSet of characters, and tested each character in mainS to see if was contained in the HashSet, because each such test costs only O(1) regardless of the size of the HashSet, which reflects the length of ref.